# Explaining relevant info for non-tangent curve-Metes and Bounds-Traverse in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metes-and-bounds

I'm trying to map out some meets and bounds from a zoning legal description. This is my fourth time using the Traverse tool for this (so still pretty new) and I'm completely thrown by the non-tangent curve descriptions. The best explanation I found so far is [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/traverse-file-format.htm) but it doesn't cover enough.

So my question is this: What is the relevant info to enter in the ArcMap Traverse tool from the example below?

It reads like this:
"*Along the arc of a non-tangent curve to the right, whose radius bears North 04 deg 54' 54'' East, said curve being subtended by a central angle of 23 deg 59' 42'', having a radius of 1382.70 feet and an arc length of 579.06 feet to a point of tangency."*

My current guess is that something like:
 *Curve Angle:23 deg 59' 42" Arc:579.06 Radial Direction: North 04 deg 54' 54" East Right*

I want to get this right.

[image]

Comment: There's a good description of the different parts of a curve in the context of metes and bounds, on this course website: http://sfrc.ufl.edu/courses/SUR4403gibson/. Module 4, Lecture 17, supporting documents: Metes and Bounds Descriptions.doc (you do have to download it).

Comment: I'm not afraid of reading/learning. Thanks I'll definitely check them out.

Answer (score 1):

first box: curve
second box radius
third box: 1382.70
fourth box: chord
fifth box: 579.06

---

chordirection: 4.5454-1
Turn: You need to give me the sentence before and after to see how it concave!